# How do I handle Visual Studio shutdown properly?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions, envdte

I'm trying to handle Visual Studio shutdown in my add-in. The problem is once the shutdown has started various DTE objects methods will no longer work and will instead trigger `COMException`s with `E_FAIL` error code and so the add-in can no longer work properly.

I therefore need to somehow detect the moment when the shutdown is initiated. There're `EnvDTE.DTE.Events.SolutionEvents` and `EnvDTE.DTE.Events.DTEEvents` classes but all the events inside them are marked "infrastructure only" so it looks like I shouldn't subscribe to them.

What's the right way to detect that Visual Studio has started to shut down and so DTE is no longer fully usable?

Comment: Sure, DTEEvents.OnBeginShutdown ought to work.  These extension interfaces are marked this way because Microsoft doesn't want to help you when you call them for support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio provides [QueryClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.package.queryclose.aspx) method to handle the VS shut down in VS packages.

To use this, override this method in your `Package` class, and do the actions you want to perform during the shutdown.